# spaCy Matcher conditional or/and Python

Tags: python, nlp, spacy, matcher

I want to categorize the following keywords:

```
import spacy
from spacy.matcher import PhraseMatcher

nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
phrase_matcher = PhraseMatcher(nlp.vocab)

cat_patterns = [nlp(text) for text in ('cat', 'cute', 'fat')]
dog_patterns = [nlp(text) for text in ('dog', 'fat')]

matcher = PhraseMatcher(nlp.vocab)
matcher.add('Category1', None, *cat_patterns)
matcher.add('Category2', None, *dog_patterns)

doc = nlp("I have a white cat. It is cute and fat; I have a black dog. It is fat,too")
matches = matcher(doc)
for match_id, start, end in matches:
    rule_id = nlp.vocab.strings[match_id]  # get the unicode ID, i.e. 'CategoryID'
    span = doc[start : end]  # get the matched slice of the doc
    print(rule_id, span.text)

#Output
#Category1 cat
#Category1 cute
#Category1 fat
#Category2 fat
#Category2 dog
#Category1 fat
#Category2 fat
```

However, my expected output is if the text contains cat and cute or cat and fat together, it will fall in the first category; if the text contains dog and fat together, then it will fall in the second category.

```
#Category1 cat cute
#Category1 cat fat
#Category2 dog fat
```

Is it possible to do it using the similar algorithm? Thank you

Comment: What do you mean by "text contains cat and cute or cat and fat together"? In the same sentence?

Comment: Hi, it looks like the expected output: category 1 - cat cute, for example.

Answer (score 0):

From the spaCy documentation on Matchers (https://spacy.io/usage/rule-based-matching), there is no way to detect 2 different tokens separated by an arbitrary number of tokens. If you knew how many tokens were between "cat" and "fat", for example, then you could use wildcard patterns (https://spacy.io/usage/rule-based-matching#adding-patterns-wildcard), but it looks like from your example that distance between tokens can vary.

Two solutions that I can see to solve your problem:

1. Keep track of matches in your `for` loop using some sort of data structure. If all the tokens you are looking for end up being found, then add that match to your final results.
2. Use regular expressions to detect what you are looking for. spaCy does have great tools for rule-based matching, but it looks like you aren't using any linguistic aspects of the words you are searching for. A simple regex like `/cat.*?fat/` will find the matches you are looking for.